# Fail2ban banned IPs gone when restarting

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

Upgraded f2b to v0.10.5, and it is banning normally according to my old jails that i copied from my previous version.

But when on restarting the service, it persist only the IPs that was banned with the configured enabled jails. All manually banned IPs like `fail2ban-client set sshd banip 1.2.3.4` are gone when i do restart.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in this version v0.10.5 that manual banned IPs not saved to database to be restored after restart.

So upgrading to v0.10.6 or v0.11.x solves the problem.